# What was the point of studying Vedas for Ravana?

Tags: vedas, ramayana, upanishads, ravana, knowledge

I mean if Ravana had to be bad even after studying the Vedas what was the point of it? What did he learn from it?

Comment: Having knowledge about something is one thing and applying the knowledge is another. Don't relate both of them. It's completely on Ravana what he wishes to do. He got the knowledge, now what to do with that knowledge is completely on him.

Comment: Ravana was a Brahmin so it was his duty to study the Vedas